# What is 'pink' and what is 'magenta'?

Tags: word-choice, image-identification

A major political row has broken out in Britain over the colour of this bus.

[image: "Woman to Woman minibus]

[Image from [The Daily Telegraph](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03194/Vote-Labour-for-Ho_3194725b.jpg)]

The bus is sponsored by the Labour Party to take high-flying female politicians around the country, to capture the votes of women at the forthcoming General Election in May. Political opponents say it is patronising to women, and gender stereotyping, to make the bus pink.

Some Labour members are now saying the colour is 'Magenta'. (capital letter justified since Magenta colour, the result of a new dye introduced at the time, after the Battle of Magenta.)

So what is it, pink or Magenta?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is opinion based.

Comment: Go ask at a paint store.  Colors cannot be reliably reproduced on the web.

Comment: @Centaurus No, **this is not opinion-based.** Colors have discrete, reproducible characteristics related to particular mixes of spectral frequencies. The emotional baggage that people ascribe to color-names is opinion based, but the actual color is not.

Comment: If we want a comparison chart, [Wikipedia offers this](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magenta). I just wish 'razzle dazzle pink' were possible here, but sadly it's not. You can decide (1) which tone best matches the above picture; (2) whether the picture accurately matches the actual bus (might depend if there's a gritter ahead); (3) how standard the terminology given by Wikipedia in this chart is; (4) why this isn't on Fashion SE.

Comment: Please don't have extended discussion in comments, also please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *All Pinks Are Magenta—and All Magentas are Purple*

Pink and magenta have the same hue.  What distinction there is to be found between magenta and pink lies along other axes than that of hue.  All pinks are magenta and all magentas are purple, and by extension, pink is a purple.  However, it does not work the other direction: it does not mean that all purples are magenta nor that [all magentas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_magenta) are pink, let alone that all purples are pink.

Here’s [the HSV color wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory), a two-dimensional representation of all the hues the human eye can see. The numbers on the outside represent degrees, and the colors at the outside are the pure, fully saturated hues.  You can find magenta on the outside of the color wheel, but to find pink, you have to move in from wherever you found magenta towards the center of the wheel.

[image: HSV color wheel]

The picture you posted has a hue of around 330°. This is the [classic printer’s magenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_magenta#Process_magenta_.28pigment_magenta.29_.28printer.27s_magenta.29_.281890s.29), which is closer to red than it is to blue.  However, the kind of [pure magenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_magenta#Web_colors_magenta_and_fuchsia_.281990s.29) you get on your monitor when you mix equal parts red and blue light has a hue of around 300°. This has more blue and less red in it than your picture does, being exactly halfway between the two red and blue light primaries.  To distinguish the on-screen magenta from the printer’s version, some people have taken to calling [the one at 300° by names like *web magenta* or *fuschia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_magenta#Web_colors_magenta_and_fuchsia_.281990s.29).

Given that red has a hue of around 0° (or 360°),  the color in your picture is half-way between red and magenta, since 330° is halfway between 300° and 360°.  Three hundred and thirty degrees is the hue of “process magenta” caused by mixing pigments. In that regard, the vehicle in your picture is magenta in hue, and people have come to call that hue magenta because they are used to the magenta pigment using in CMYK processing.  This is a different magenta than the one you get from adding equal parts of red and blue light, however.  Sometimes this process magenta’s hue is called *rose*, which you will note is a synonym of *pink*.

The important thing to understand is that **pink and magenta have the same hue**.  To get to pink on the color wheel, start at 300° and travel inwards from magenta towards the white dot in the center. If you want to think of magenta like the printer’s color, then you may instead start at 330° and then move inwards.  Because I’m used to thinking of these things, I do not think of that second version as *pink*, but rather reddish-pink since it has more red in it than it has blue.  I reserve *magenta* for the color that is half and half.

If you use RGB, then the point I sampled has a red value of 195/256 and a blue value of 101/256; it also has a green value of 9/256, which desaturates or muddies it. Because those are not "full" values of 256/256, they are also darker than the bright colors around the outer edge of the color wheel.  You can tell how much more red there is there than there is blue (195 vs. 101) in your picture, which makes it a more reddish color than the hot electric magenta that comes from mixing equal parts red and blue light.  But sometimes people call this magenta.

You may feel that your color is not on the wheel; nor indeed are many colors.  That’s because it takes three axes to represent human color vision.  We can show that by extending the wheel into a cylinder.  The bright (Brightness/Value = 100%) colors of the original disk are at the top of the cylinder. The colors you were missing are somewhere below the surface:

[image: color cylinder from wikipedia]

**Speaking technically not politically** the way scientists understand and explain these matters, magenta is a non-spectral color (that is, one not in the rainbow) occurring along [the line of purples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_purples). There are infinitely many colors between red and blue, none of which occur in the rainbow; all are purples by definition.

[image: line of purples from wikipedia]

Depending on which representational color model you are thinking about, magenta can be described in several different ways:

1. Under the HSV color model, magenta is a fully saturated (100%) color with a hue of 300°; its value is also full at 100%.
2. Under the RGB model, magenta is created by mixing equal parts of red and blue light without any green at all.
3. Under the CMYK model, magenta is a primary color and has none of the others in it whatsoever.

Formally speaking, pink is a desaturated form of magenta, one that has been “lightened” (made closer to a neutral grey/white) by adding green light to it in the RGB model, or via equivalent mechanisms in the other models. Just as white is but bright grey and black dark grey yet all three have the same neutral hue, pink is a lightened magenta but of the same hue. These are precise, measurable definitions with reproducible qualities that are not subject to personal opinion.

However, those unfamiliar with the technical matters of color theory, human biology, or physics will call anything anything, and you’ll never get anyone to agree on this. One person might call magenta dark pink and another call pink light magenta. Neither is more or less correct than the other. People use the words ascribed to colors—that is, they use color-names — for devious purposes of marketing, politics, and propaganda, not excluding pejorative uses and name-calling. All this is beyond the scope of any strictly technical definition, which is invariant and not subject to spin-doctoring.

The bottom line is:

1. The technical answer is that pink is a “lightened” form of magenta and that magenta is but one type of purple; none of those colors occur in the prismatic splitting of white light. The hue is the same for both pink and magenta; only the saturation and value differ.  So the H is the same but the S and V are smaller in magnitude.
2. The political answer is whatever you care to make it.

Comment: Thank you. I must confess, not being one previously versed in graphics, colour etc. that I have not taken the time to understand all the technicalities. But since you seem to have approached the question in the greatest depth, yours, in my opinion, is worthy of consideration as the correct answer.

Comment: light red is pink but is not magenta. light orange is pink but is not magenta. light orchid is definitely not pink. subtractive Purple + yellow = brown, subtractive magenta + yellow = red. orchid(true magenta/300hue) is only pink when lightened if it is extremely bright, at 80% brightness, it will look lilac and decisively not pink. From the point of view of practicality, true magenta can be either defined as any color that mixes with yellow to produce red/"pink", or any color that can be mixed with green to make a color which is mostly gray(more extreme).

Answer (score 6):

If you compare the wikipedia pages for [pink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink) (pink is pale red) and [magenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magenta) (magenta is violet-red or purplish-red), the difference seems obvious, and the bus looks definitely magenta.

However, most people do not, in everyday life, divide colours up into shades like magenta, cerise, violet or lilac and tend to call all of those *pink*.

So the issue is not which colour is is *technically*, but what is that colour usually called. And then the answer is, I'm afraid, pink.

To add to the gender based stereotypes, one might expect *women* to make a distinction between cerise, magenta, lilac and pink, but for *men* its probably all pink. Unless they wear it. Then it's anything, even orange, but don't call it pink.

[image]

Comment: +1 You echo my own views. *Cerise* is another colour Labour are now calling it. But the colour choice does seem to have been a major gaffe.

Comment: A _gaffe_, by a political party? How on earth would that be possible? You mean to say that the _public_ is making a major mistake by misinterpreting the obviously good intentions of their representatives?

Comment: The public are just enjoying the fun, at least those of us are who enjoy elections for the hilarious incidents which arise during campaigns.

Comment: Isn't that what they are for? We pay taxes for the politicians to entertain us. Actually I have volunteered to pay my taxes at least in part to the UK. Politicians on that side of the channel provide better comedy.

Comment: I tend to agree with you. I think it is to do with the nature of the House of Commons chamber, gentleman's club atmosphere. But I used to be involved at a local level, and the election campaigns have left me with a fund of anecdotes to dine on.

Comment: Violet and lilac are shades of purple, not pink in the slightest.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox: Like I said, for men, [there aren't that many colours ...](http://www.geekinheels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/how_men_and_women_see_colors.jpg)

Comment: Seriously though. Even men wouldn't call violet and lilac *pink*. They are clearly in the purple category, similar to "grape" and "lavender" above.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox: true, although I regularly hear people who can;t be bothered to distinguish between pink and purple unless they compare extremes like a light rose wine with a heavy red Bordeaux (which is likely to be purple, rather than red. Many of the Bordeaux wines are not exactly Bordeaux in colour. yeay!)

Comment: I can't believe I started this!

Comment: "Seam foam"?  (from the image)

Comment: That cartoon has actually [been debunked](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/).

Comment: That cartoon is sheer nonsense, and painfully sexist to boot.

Comment: You lost me at 'gender'.

Comment: Thanks for the timely chart, oerkelens. I was just about to post a question to EL&U: What color is spindrift? But now I know—although I still don't know why.