# What is the opposite word of "greyscale" (or black and white)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some words that come to mind:

- Multi-color
- Natural color
- True color
- Colored

Is any of these correct? Any better word?

**EDIT**:

As some commenters requested, I am adding context.

I am not going to use the word in any specific sentence. I am a programmer and I am trying to categorize colors used in a program into greyscale colors, and then _ (*answer here*) colors.

Comment: Take a look at the antonyms Merriam-Webster gives for "monochrome": http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/monochrome

Comment: Sorry I didn't bother about, and no-one else seems to have noticed, your being a programmer. Doesn't that mean you're working round Venn-type set logic? Wasn't that designed basically to exploit the idea that while "chalk and cheese" are no kind of opposite, nevertheless there is value in comparing their difference? The dozens of accepted colour models insist greyscales are wholly-contained subsets - never opposites - of wider models… except where white is the sum of all colours and black the absence of light, which context counts hardly at all, and less in programming.

Answer (score 27):

**full color**

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/full-color)'s definition : "The full range of colors"

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20(full)%20color)'s definition: "Not black and white"

Technically speaking a greyscale image can be considered a colored image, because white, black and grey are all colors too. Therefore, rather than opting for just the word *color*, I feel that using *full color* instead  emphasizes that a palette of colors beyond greyscale is used/available.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it: the question has been updated with a bit more information. Apparently, the poster is looking for a word to categorize all the colors in the palette that are not white, black, or shades of grey. This isn't quite the same thing as "the full range of colors," but I don't know if you want or need to make any edits to your answer.

Comment: Note that IIRC, historically, "full color" was meant to differentiate graphic formats / adapters which allowed each pixel to have an independent color (with freely adjustable R, G, B components), as in JPG or most PNG files, as opposed to other situations which forced the use of a limited colour palette (as in GIF files which are limited to 256 colors).

Comment: "Full color" always meant a full spectrum of colors. (I'm pretty sure the terms came from film photography, though I never actually checked.) Certainly, the term applies to image formats, but also to a dizzying array of other things.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the word chromatic (second definition):

> chromatic ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chromatic))
>
> Relating to or produced by color.

Some other dictionaries also include "multichromatic" as an alternative, meaning:

> multichromatic ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multichromatic))
>
> involving more than one colour.

I'm pretty sure the average literate American would understand what this word means, although it appears to be favored more in British English, as I couldn't find a definition for multichromatic in a dictionary that spelled "color" in the American spelling.

Comment: @suməlic multichromatic doesn't seem to appear in Oxford (which I just realized I've been misquoting thanks to NVZ), which I found interesting, because I've always assumed it was a real American English word.

Comment: Oh, I see! That's right, that comment was only about "multichromatic." Hmm. My spell-checker doesn't like it. I guess it's a rare word in either variety of English, but I don't think it's illegitimate in American English just because dictionaries don't list it.

Comment: @suməlic Google's built-in spell-checker doesn't like it, either. But I think it's about as close as an antonym to greyscale as one is going to get.

Comment: Polychromatic is far more common.

Comment: I suspect the more common terms in American English would be [polychrome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polychrome) and [monochrome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monochrome).

Answer (score 8):

Greyscale colours are [achromatic colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achromatic) - so we can call the complementary set **chromatic colours**.

I think the terms 'greyscale colours' and 'chromatic colours' are reasonable -  and moreover are preferable to 'chromatic' and 'achromatic', because these latter two only differ by one letter and are thus prone to confusion & typo errors.

The meaning of the term 'chromatic colours', however, is not self-evident.  So I would suggest that using the terms **greyscale colours** and **non-greyscale colours** is actually the best option, even if it lacks a bit of elegance.

Answer (score 6):

For your example usage, don't say "greyscale colors", just say "greyscale". Then color becomes the opposite of greyscale in context: "I am trying to categorize colors used in a program into greyscale and then color".

Comment: If a noun is required along with "greyscale", I think the standard in general english to use "shades", although colour theory would suggest "tones" is more appropriate. q.v. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades

Comment: Greyscale is being nominalized in the above sentence, so there is a noun.

Answer (score 5):

Fairly clearly black-and-white is not what you want; some kind of “colour” might be.

There is not now, never has been and never, under any circumstances could be anything like an antonym of greyscale, just as there is no antonym of chalk or cheese or grass or green. Greyscale does not form half of any pair, let alone of a pair of opposites.

If this is a purely linguistic question that’s all there is to it.

If not, what are you Posting about?

Comment: Thanks for the support, Robbie. The first paragraph of your post is an answer (saying that an antonym doesn't exist; although it does not have enough detail or support to be a good answer) but the rest is better suited to a comment. Now that I've upvoted your post, you should be able to leave comments directly beneath the question; I think you should do that and edit your answer to take out the parts where you ask for clarification.

Comment: The problem with opposites of words like greyscale is that it depends on what part of the word you consider more important- what’s the opposite of “big boy”?  Big girl? Small boy? Small girl? So is it a full-color scale? A grey point??

Comment: @technophyle - of course not.  A masterpiece is a piece made by a master.  Therefore the opposite could be a piece made by a novice. Or if there was a convenient opposite for piece then we could apply that as well.  I can’t think of an opposite for piece here though.   And that means to me that the word *masterpiece* is **not** like the word greyscale, the the word *doorman* is for this purpose.

Comment: Of course, the antonym of chalk _is_ cheese.

Comment: Sorry, Jeremy… you're the first person I've heard or read in 60 years of caring, who suggested "chalk" and "cheese" were antonyms.

Everyone I know sees "chalk and cheese" in the same way as "apples and pears"… ie, clearly different but equally clearly, in no way opposed… 

What made you think otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

The neutral colors black, white, and the infinite shades of grey are called that because they absorb all wavelengths equally.

In HSV they have no saturation so their hue is immaterial. In RGB all three are the same value.

So apparently you want the ***non-neutral*** colors.  Those are all the colors it takes the three kinds of cones in your eye to see.   With only one kind of rod you can see only one kind of color, the neutral kind, the monochromatic ones.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, there's not going to be one correct answer to this question. My suggestion is to use "greyscale shades" vs. "colors". If I were already locked into "greyscale colors", I'd go with "actual colors".

Answer (score 2):

From what I have learnt about colors, Black, White, and Grey (combination of Black and White) are colors which aren't directly a part of the visible spectrum and thus I'd coin the term "spectral scale" for a range of colors not containing these three.

Spectral colors are the colors that make up rainbows i.e VIBGYOR.

Also, *spectral-scale* sounds appropriate and satisfying. But, that's just an opinion.

Refer :- [Spectral Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_color)

Comment: I find it interesting that you refer to the rainbow starting with violet. I've always seen ROYGBIV, never VIBGYOR.

Comment: But there are penty of colours that don't appear in the spectrum - the obvious one being pink

Comment: The question "is pink a colour?" is like asking "Is a tomato a vegetable?", in that the answer can be yes or no depending on context.

Comment: @origimbo No, pink is always a color. It simply is not a spectral color because it cannot be produced by a single wavelength. Pink is a desaturated magenta, which being one of the purples in turn is a blend of red and blue spectral colors. See our related question on [*What is ‘pink’ and what is ‘magenta’?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/227065/2085) for FMTEYEWTK about such matters.

Comment: @tchrist Well, it could also be a flower in the genus dianthus, or the stage name of a pop singer, but otherwise this is the argument I was hoping to forestall by referring to tomatoes.

Comment: @ChrisH Like Grey, Pink is a derived color and the colours from which it is derived are a part of the spectrum and thus by transitivity, pink is a part of the spectrum. Such isn't the case with Grey because black isn't a part of the spectrum although white is. I hope that clears it out.

Comment: @AshishPandey from my physics point of view, there's no way you can call pink part of the spectrum any more than white.  The whole point about ROYGBIV colours is that you can define their wavelengths (e.g. red is light that falls in about 600-750 nm).  For pink you can't. It can only be expressed in terms like white (i.e. broadband) with extra red.  "Being in the spectrum" can't be transitive or all colours in a broad sense, with the exception of black would be in the spectrum.

Comment: @ChrisH I get your point very well. You're being extremely atomic here. There are molecules too. That's all I have to say.

Comment: An intersting analogy.  Molecules are made from atoms, but aren't atoms themselves. Pink is made from spectral colours but isn't one.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, that is what I always wanted to say about pink.

Answer (score 1):

For your application rgbColors or some form (RGB_Colors, rgbScale) would probably be best suited. HSL/HSV could be used, but I feel that the former is most fitting.

Comment: It *could* work, but some colors are RGBA ones ;)

Comment: In the RGB world all the greyscale colors are in the RGB spectrum as well.

Comment: @technophyle I would say the transparency represented by the alpha channel is not part of the color value. It says how much the color is depending on the background. But on the other hand, you could have more color channels like IR and UV.

Comment: @Jim All neutral colors have R=G=B in the RGB model, and S=0 with H immaterial in the HSV model.

Answer (score 1):

A grayscale color is a fully desaturated color, i.e. a color with zero saturation. The opposite of that, in a technical context, might be a fully saturated color, with maximal saturation. But between these opposites there is a whole range of colors which have neither zero nor full saturation.

Judging from your context, you probably don't want the opposite but the complement (in the set-theoretic meaning). You could describe them as “colors with nonzero saturation”, but that's way harder to understand than “non-grayscale colors”, and less elegant as well, so I wouldn't suggest actually using that.

The terms you suggest, like “natural color” or “true color”, tend to describe a picture which is composed of color from a certain set, with the assumption that a close representation of the colored original is attempted. So while these words may be good to describe the colors used in a picture, I would not use them for a single color. After all, what would a “multi-colored color” be, since each color is by definition exactly that: *one* color. On the other hand, a “colored color” sounds like a repetition without semantic meaning, similar to wet water. If you call these things “colors”, including the desaturated ones, then they are *all* “colored”. (You could choose a different convention, and call some of these things “colors” and others “gray scales” or whatever. But then you would have the even harder task of finding a common term to describe the union of both of these. This would quickly become confusing.)

If I had to pick a single non-compound word to describe a single non-grayscale color as such, I'd go for “chromatic”, as already suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The word pair that comes to mind for me is *shade* : *hue*

Where *shade* refers to greyscale and *hue* refers to colors

See [What’s the Difference between a Hue, Tint, Shade and Tone ?](https://avaminzhang.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/whats-the-difference-between-a-hue-tint-shade-and-tone/)

Comment: In other contexts, the opposite of "greyscale" might be "saturated", "color", "full color"...

Answer (score -1):

For your purposes, maybe **polychrome** would do.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polychrome):

> relating to, made with, or decorated in several colors

Answer (score -1):

This is just to point out that *chromatic*, which has been suggested by several answerers, is used in this context in published literature.

From [*Digital Color Imaging Handbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OxlBqY67rl0C&lpg=PA762&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false):

> *Hue*. Attribute of a visual sensation according to which an area appears to be similar to one of the perceived colors: red, yellow,
>   green, and blue, or to a combination of two of them.
>
> *Achromatic color.* Perceived color devoid of hue.
>
> *Chromatic color.* Perceived color possessing a hue.

Equivalent usage is attested [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=8_TxzK2B-5MC&lpg=PA379&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3TIeAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA272&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2tW91BWeNq4C&lpg=PA204&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA409#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=yQ1_AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA103&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptpXbW1NaeMC&lpg=PA8&dq=%22chromatic%20color%22&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=%22chromatic%20color%22&f=false), ...